# How to replace only 2nd character from a string in R

Tags: r, string, substitution

```
s<-"HsdKjnsjsHLKsmH"
```

how to substitute a character at a particular position in R
replace only second "H" in the string `s` with "Q"

Comment: `gsub("(^.)(.)",replacement = "\\1Q", "HsdKjnsjsHLKsmH" ,perl=T)`

Comment: @R.S. This does not return the desired output.

Comment: @avid_userR. yes, my bad. I misread the question.

Comment: This should have done it : `gsub("(h)([^h]*)(h)",replacement = "\\1\\2Q", "HsdKjnsjsHLKsmH" ,perl=T, ignore.case = T)`

Comment: can you please explain the code?

Comment: The stuff in bracket is not just matched , but captured for reuse. Here we are telling it  to retain 1st and 2nd match (\\1 and \\2 )but adding Q after the second match , and not to bother about the 3rd match at all.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `gregexpr` and `substr`. `gregexpr` finds all matches and returns the position of the matches. Using the position of the second match, we can then replace the second "H" with "Q" using `substr`. This guarantees that it's always the second "H" that we're replacing:

```
s = "HsdKjnsjsHLKsmH"

pos <- gregexpr("H", s)[[1]][2]

substr(s, pos, pos) <- "Q"
# [1] "HsdKjnsjsQLKsmH"
```

Another method using `stringr`, and making it a :

```
library(stringr)

str_pos_replace <- function(string, pattern, replacement, pos=1){
  str_locate_all(string, pattern)[[1]][pos,, drop=FALSE] %>%
    `str_sub<-`(string, ., value = replacement)
}

str_pos_replace(s, "H", "QQQ", 2)
# [1] "HsdKjnsjsQQQLKsmH"
```

Comment: I think that's a great solution because it provides a general approach to match `x` at `n-th` position. 1up!

Comment: How would you replace 2nd "H" with "QQQ" using the first approach ?

Comment: @AndreElrico Good question. I have yet to figure that out. In the meantime, the `stringr` method works.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "HsdKjnsjsHLKsmH"
sub("[^H]*H[^H]*\\KH","Q",s,perl=T)


#[1] "HsdKjnsjsQLKsmH"
```

Comment: This just removes everything I matched before `\\K` from selection. That means  `[^H]*H[^H]*` to be specific. I could use a `look behind`, but that doesn't work with unspecific lengths like `[^H]*`.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know we could do this. As for lookbehind and `[^H]*` , that must be because lookbehind in R works only when  the length is known beforehand. This works, even though it is not of much practical  use-   `sub("(?<=H[^H]{8})H","Q", "HsdKjnsjsHLKsmH",perl=T)`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
s <- "HsdKjnsjsHLKsmH"
sub("(H[^H]*)H", "\\1Q", s)
```

If you want to generalize the code above, here is a function that does so.

```
replaceSecond <- function(s, old, new){
    pattern <- paste0("(", old, "[^", old, "]*)", old)
    new <- paste0("\\1", new)
    sub(pattern, new, s)
}

replaceSecond(s, "H", "Q")
#[1] "HsdKjnsjsQLKsmH"
```